# How to add a ms-dos partition table to a loop device?

Tags: linux, partition, virtualization, loop-device

I recently made a dd from a disk partition. I want to use it as a disk in a virtual machine. I can't because the disk has no partition table.

Can I had a partition table to a loop device? how?

[apparently a similar question exists here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41137/convert-image-of-a-partition-into-image-of-a-disk-with-partition-table?rq=1)  If someone knows how to do this without duplicating all data, that  would be great.

I did  `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=myfile`

I can't copy the full sda disk because it's just too big.

Comment: Just use `fdisk` (or other utility) as you normally would.

Comment: @patrick does not work, because there is no space on the device for it.

Comment: I just tried it, works perfectly for me. You should add the exact commands you've used (all the way from creating the image to the fdisk command).

Comment: @Patrick I'm guessing the OP did something like `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=myfile` and now wants to create a MBR partition structure around the current contents of `myfile` so it is useful as a virtual hard disk rather than simply a single partition dump.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling that's exactly it. I can't copy the complete sda because I don't have enough space/interest on that.

Comment: @Guerrio Please click "edit" below the question, and add that information to your question.

Comment: You can use the image without a partition table just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the original drive, then delete the image and create it again with:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=myfile bs=512 seek=2048
```

That will leave the usual 1 MiB of space at the start for the partition table to be added later.

You also may want to look into using qcow2 for the image instead of a full, raw image file that contains all of the junk in the unused blocks.

Comment: Thanks. Why 1 Mbyte? The partition table plus the boot sector usually takes 512bytes

Comment: @Guerrio, because partition tools these days align the partition to a MiB boundary for performance reasons.  Also you need to leave some room usually for the boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
sda1_size=$((`blkdev --getsize64 /dev/sda1`/1024/1024+1))
dd if=/dev/sda of=myfile bs=1M count=$(($sda1_size+1))
```

Start dd for entire sda, but copy only until the first partition is covered. Achieved by adding +1 MiB to the count. This is assuming that sda1 is at the very beginning of the disk. If there's an empty gap larger than 1MiB, add more than +1.

Rather than the math stuff, you could also just look how large in MiB the partition is in any partitioning program, and then just be generous and add a bit to it.

Comment: Thanks. Why 1 Mbyte? The partition table plus the boot sector usually take 512bytes.

Comment: Many reasons. dd is slow when copying in 512 byte sectors; partitions are often MiB-aligned these days; and in general it's just better to copy a MiB or two too many than too few.